Force refresh from outlook web addin to show changes made by graph api (attachments added)
I've got an add in for outlook which is successfully updating the attachments via the graph API. However, it doesn't show up in outlook desktop client unless you close the client and re-open it and navigate to drafts.
Is there a way to get this to feedback more quickly, otherwise the feature becomes redundant.
Cheers

Outlook Desktop caches most of the information and syncs with Exchange time to time. This is how it works. You can set your Outlook to "online" mode and it will sync immediately, but this is probably not what you will be able to do for your customers. Changes made on back-end will not appear right away in Outlook, period. On other hand what is so special are you doing, so you need Graph and cannot do with OfficeJS? Changes made with Office JS will appear right away for all Outlook clients, including desktop.

Did you read Manage an item's attachments in a compose form in Outlook?
